# Redirigir un iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un iframe que reproduce un video de una página distinta a la mia, el problema es que cuando hago click en el me redirige a esa página y yo necesito que me redirija a otra página distinta.
Probe encerrar el iframe entre etiquetas anchor, agregarle un onclick, pero nada funciona.
Alguien tiene idea de como puedo hacer esto?

```
<iframe src="paginaEjemplo.com" frameborder="0" width="310" height="175"></iframe>
```

Como ven al hacer click voy a paginaEjemplo.com y yo quiero ir a pagina2.com
Desde ya muchas gracias.
El código sería:

Comment: Hola. La mejor forma de contarnos qué estás haciendo es con código. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Con el IFRAME estas "importando" TODO el codigo de "paginaEjemplo.com" y si en este codigo el video tiene un enlace a otra pagina, es lo que se ejecutara.

Revisa el codigo de la pagina que importas para ver que es lo que codigo realmente estas incluyendo en tu pagina